# IN divi conatct form submissions getting weird emails in inbox

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, divi-theme

In my Wordpress site I have configured the divi contact from module and After submission I am getting some weird emails like I am getting message pattern as it is in the email rather then actual details of user.

And when I tried to submit the same form multiple times, form is working correctly and getting desired details.

I have tried sending email multiple times.
Checked server error logs and found xmlrpc file enabled and multiple hits on that file.

Below is the email I am getting form user.

Hi,
you got a message from xyz website.
this is from %%name%%, the email id is %%email%%, company name is %%company_name%%.
And the message was ...
%%msg%% .
%%subscribe%%**

This is the desired result for form submission.

Hi,
you got a message from xyz website.
this is from ABC, the email id is abc@gmail.com, company name is ABC.
And the message was ...
ABC .
I also subscribe the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is from %%name%%, the email id is %%email%%, company name is %%company_name%%. And the message was ... %%msg%% . %%subscribe%%**
```

Here %%name%%, %%email%%, %%company_name%% are the ID field of the form fields. Make sure you have entered the correct values of the ID field. There are chances that you may have entered the Label value instead of ID value.

Kindly share the screenshot of the Contact Form Message Pattern screen where you enter these details. So we can help you.

Comment: Issue is resolved, that is not the issue, It was a spam message and prevented these kind of messages using cleanTalk or Wpbruiser plugin, got resolved my issue.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer so that others will also get the benefit

Answer (score 0):

that is not the issue, It was a spam message and prevented these kind of messages using cleanTalk or Wpbruiser plugin, got resolved my issue.